# Why is there a delay updating my UIView

Tags: ios, swift

When I retrieve data with NSURLSession and want to update my view after the data is available from the server there is a delay updating the view about 15 sec.

```
var url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://example.com/app/api.php")
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
  self.myLabel.text = "completion"
  self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
  return})
dataTask.resume()
```

Additional: It doesn't matter if I call setNeedsDisplay.

Any suggestions what's wrong with my code or how to avoid such a delay?

Comment: What data is it that you want to display? Please provide some comments in your code. Is it the text in the label?

Comment: No, it's not the text in the label. The data response from the server works perfect (println). My goal is to change the label text as soon as the response is available to inform the user.

Comment: have you tried to create a queue and update you ui elements that block?

Comment: No, is it even possible? Because the ui elements are updated on the main threat. Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Try setting the session's delegateQueue property to [NSOperationQueue mainQueue].

Comment: You are somewhat wrong in your understanding. UI elements are supposed to be updated on the main thread, but they will update from a background thread, but usually with a long delay like you're observing. The queue you get with the shared session is a background queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to rdelmar who put me in the right direction here is my corrected code:

```
var url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://www.connected-media.de/app/api.php")

var sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

var URLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

var dataTask = URLSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response:      NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
self.myLabel.text = "completion"
return})        

dataTask.resume()
```